# How do you represent NULL values in a bulk update file for SQL?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to do a bulk update on a table from a file with a bunch of \N values (I'm assuming these are supposed to be null,) but I get errors like

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 14 (CS).

It's for an assignment, and the text file came from the data files provided through the publishing company or whatever (which is actually an ASP.NET book.) I've been just using the Visual Studio SQL functionality, rather than SQL Server, and so I don't know if that may be causing a problem... But...

Is there some way I can properly represent NULL values in the text file so that it will update the table the way it's supposed to? I already set the fields to be nullable, and that didn't work. I tried a find and replace on \N to NULL and that didn't work...

Comment: Please show us a sample from your import file. Also, is that `\N` (a literal backslash followed by an `n` or `N` character), or a Carriage Return / New Line character? (typically represented using backslash as an escape character). SQL Server Bulk Insert does not support escape characters, unfortunately.

Comment: A sample line would be `St. Louis Cardinals 18733  643511  86022  171614  28048  7203  9842  76001  243594  57418  69716  \N  \N  \N  .379  .267` It's straight text, so they're literal backslash capital N characters. I'm guessing SQL must be attempting to import them as a straight string (rather than a null value) and is complaining because those are supposed to be ints or doubles. That's why I'm asking how to represent them so that they are NULL in the database... Do I just blank them out? Is there some kind of value I can put there that will make SQL go "Oh... Null"